# iPhone App Icon Replaced by New App

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I created an iPhone app "App1" and installed on my device and everything worked fine. Now, I copied all the code from App1 and made App2. But now when I run the App2 is replaced the icon of App1 and completely replaces the App1 with App2 on the iPhone device. What can I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Bundle identifier in your Info.plist of the second app to something different than in the first app.

Comment: I did that and than ran the app on the device. It installs the app but never runs. When I click on the app from my device then it runs correctly. Also, in XCode it says "Failed to upload App2.app". App2 is the new app which is the copy of App1.

Comment: Disconnecting and restarting XCode did the trick! Thanks man!

Comment: Thanks! Now for some reason the iPhone Simulator is having problems. It says Springboard failed to launch. When I changed the bundler identifier to old app (App1) it started working. Any ideas what is going on?